# Kendo Angular 4 Unmet Peer Dependency and Cannot find module "rxjs/operators/combineLatest"

Tags: angular, npm, kendo-ui, .net-core, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to install Kendo UI in an Angular 4 application and I am getting all kinds of errors.

First, I ran this command:

```
npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs @progress/kendo-angular-l10n @progress/kendo-angular-intl
```

And it gave me the following output:

```
npm WARN saveError Problems were encountered
npm WARN saveError Please correct and try again.
npm WARN saveError invalid: have rxjs@5.4.2 (expected: 5.5.0) C:\projects\myapp\node_modules\rxjs
npm WARN saveError peer invalid: rxjs@^5.5.0, required by @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs@2.0.0
npm WARN saveError peer invalid: rxjs@^5.5.0, required by @progress/kendo-angular-popup@2.0.0
npm WARN saveError extraneous: rxjs@5.4.2 C:\projects\myapp\node_modules\rxjs
npm WARN saveError extraneous: symbol-observable@1.0.4 C:\projects\myapp\node_modules\symbol-observable
MyApp.web@0.0.0 C:\projects\myapp\
+-- @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs@2.0.0
| +-- @progress/kendo-angular-popup@2.0.0
| | `-- @progress/kendo-popup-common@1.2.3
| +-- @progress/kendo-date-math@1.1.1
| `-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@^5.5.0
+-- @progress/kendo-angular-intl@1.3.0
| `-- @telerik/kendo-intl@1.3.2
+-- @progress/kendo-angular-l10n@1.0.5
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.4.2 invalid
```

After doing some reading, I though this might just be a warning, so I continued on, and added the

```
import { IntlModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-intl';
import { DateInputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';
```

to my app module.

When I run the app, I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "rxjs/operators/combineLatest"
    at Object.<anonymous> (messages.js:23)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap ce6c1efdfd0ad0f85363:657)
    at fn (bootstrap ce6c1efdfd0ad0f85363:85)
    at Object.<anonymous> (messages.js:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap ce6c1efdfd0ad0f85363:657)
    at fn (bootstrap ce6c1efdfd0ad0f85363:85)
    at Object.<anonymous> (date-pattern.js:242)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap ce6c1efdfd0ad0f85363:657)
    at fn (bootstrap ce6c1efdfd0ad0f85363:85)
    at Object.<anonymous> (localized-messages.directive.js:32)
```

Here is my `packages.json` file:
https://gist.github.com/chriskooken/70bda141210f1ba174876e4018c6dd9c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had the same issue. 
This message: npm WARN saveError invalid: have rxjs@5.4.2 (expected: 5.5.0)
explains your issue. Update your rxjs version to 5.5.0 or newer.

Comment: This worked, thanks. These errors are so cryptic sometimes. Thanks!